# Deferring a noun belonging to a preposition until after a conjunction

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it grammatically correct to defer the use of a noun (belonging to preposition) until after a conjunction?

1. In order to scale to (*deferred noun: multi-objective optimisation*) and study multi-objective optimisation, ...
2. We demonstrate how one can help out with (*deferred noun: poverty*) and mitigate poverty in Africa.
3. ... so that the community can open up to (*deferred noun: migrant populations*) and accept the cultures of migrant populations.

Comment: See a related Q about omission of subject from ELL: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/148269/omission-of-the-subject-for-friendliness

Comment: The phenomenon is often referred to as “right node raising”. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising

Comment: @RichardZ that is exactly what I was looking for. If you can turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Richard Z mentioned in a comment, the syntax that I am using is valid and is called: [Right Node Raising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's grammatically correct; however, your examples all sound very strange for other reasons.

---

> In order to scale to ____<sub>i</sub> and study {multi-objective optimisation}<sub>i</sub>, […]

Google cannot find a single example of the phrase ["scale to multi-objective optimisation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scale+to+multi-objective+optimisation%22), which makes sense, because "scale to" is usually used with large numbers; for example, a given software architecture might be said to ["scale to millions of"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scale+to+millions+of%22) requests/users/records/etc., meaning that it can support those large numbers. (I'm guessing you really mean "generalize to" rather than "scale to".)

Furthermore, I find it hard to imagine a situation where you might describe the same system as both "scaling to" something and "studying" that thing, at least without serious clarifying context.

Depending on the intended meaning, a better phrasing might be "In order to generalize the system so it can study multi-objective optimisation, […]".

---

> We demonstrate how one can help out with ____<sub>i</sub> and mitigate poverty<sub>i</sub> in Africa.

This doesn't make sense, because *[help out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/help%20out) with* and [*mitigate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mitigate) mean roughly the same thing, and are both too vague for there to be a meaningful distinction being drawn. (Google finds no results for ["help out with, but not mitigate"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22help+out+with%2C+but+not+mitigate%22) or ["mitigate, but not help out with"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mitigate%2C+but+not+help+out+with%22); it's almost inconceivable that someone would say either of those, because the distinction just isn't viable.) You should choose just one or the other.

---

> […] so that the community can open up to ____<sub>i</sub> and accept the cultures of {migrant populations}<sub>i</sub>.

This one is not as bad as the others, but it's still a bit odd, because "open up to" and "accept" are both pretty vague and similar, so you have a similar problem as the "help out with"/"mitigate" example. Here the primary distinction is actually in the noun phrases; there's not much difference between "open up to […]" and "accept […]", but there's a big difference between "[…] migrant populations" and "[…] the cultures of migrant populations". So the problem with this example is that it downplays the real difference and emphasizes a difference-that-isn't-one. To fix this, I'd suggest "[…] so that the community can open up to migrant populations and accept their cultures."

If you still want to keep your proposed structure, you can; but in that case I'd suggest adding commas:

> […] so that the community can open up to, and accept the cultures of, migrant populations.

to avoid this misinterpretation:

> […] so that the community can open up to ____<sub>i</sub> and accept {the cultures of migrant populations}<sub>i</sub>.

which, in addition to not having your intended meaning, would have the same problem as the "help out with"/"mitigate" example.

Answer (score -2):

These formulations are correct:

1. We demonstrate how one can help out and mitigate poverty in Africa.
2. ... so that the community can open up and accept the cultures of migrant populations.

Your question is not clear to me, but I can tell you that all three of your sentences/formulations are bad when what you refer to as the *deferred noun* is missing.

These are no good:

```
In order to scale to and study multi-objective optimisation, ...
We demonstrate how one can help out with and mitigate poverty in Africa.
... so that the community can open up to and accept the cultures of migrant populations.
```

In addition, *multi-objective optimisation* sounds a bit wordy and hollow.

Comment: The deferred nouns are **not** missing in any of the sentences. They follow immediately after the second verbs.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford  Read what I said.  I did not say they are missing. This is getting a little ridiculous.  It is very clear to me that this website is not being properly monitored.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford: This site is unfriendly and poorly managed.  I shall not be here long.  I just wanted to send you an unambiguous message and register my displeasure.

Comment: @JasonBassford Patriot is completely correct. You've misatributed your own idea to them. It doesn't appear anywhere in their post

Comment: I have updated the question to make what I am asking clearer, I meant to ask whether it is ok to move a otherwise repeated noun to after a conjunction such as "and"